# Transparency in Background Picture

Tags: java, android, xml, transparent

I want to achive that I have a transparent background BUT with a picture !
So if got this in the XML file of my layout :

```
android:background="@drawable/wallpaperpic"
```

Now I want to transparent it so the background menu (f.ex. widgets or app menu) is seeable but also my `drawable/wallpaperpic` and the rest of my buttons etc are normal (100%).Hopefully I was able to express my self !

My Background : https://amazingpict.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/polygon-texture.jpg

I want to have this[image]

WHERE you also can see my background picture a bit

Comment: Just to clarify - you're looking to add a background like in the second picture where it shows the "Wikipedia" result? None of the other pictures have a transparent background.

Comment: Oh wait, you want to show something on top of the system menu, i.e. the stock Android launcher?

Comment: Thats right. Transparent background with a wallpaper. That was the fastest which I founded ^^

Comment: In that case, you're probably looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341922/android-launching-activity-on-top-of-other-apps

Comment: Exactly thats right !

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the alpha property of the view, like:

```
yourView.serAlpha(10);
```

Comment: I allready tried that but this makes firstly the view completly transparent and the background is going to be white . So thats not a workng solution :(

Answer (score 0):

If, as I'm guessing now, you have two layouts, one within the other, where the parent layout has the background, you can do this in the child layout:

```
android:background="@null"
```

This way, you can see the background, and your elements are intact.

Comment: Ive got only one layout which has a backgroung image.In this layout I want to transparent the wallpaper so you can see the android menu of the user a bit

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is to convert your image to a PNG and add an alpha channel.

Option 2 (which I would recommend) is to have a separate view that acts as your background, and set the alpha property for this view only. You can use a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) to put this background view underneath your other controls.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion use TintableBackgroundView.

[TintableBackgroundView.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/TintableBackgroundView.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you launch your activity the normal way, the system will not render anything behind it (i.e. the launcher will be completely gone - it could even remove it from memory).

You'll need to implement your activity as an alert window. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341922/android-launching-activity-on-top-of-other-apps) has details on how to implement it.